# Issuing many Redux dispatch calls from callbacks in XHR requests gradually slows React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, redux, react-redux

I am working on a React application that is able to write many files at a time to a server. To upload these files I am using bluebird's Promise.map and uploading each file using XmlHttpRequests within a promise with a concurrency of 3 at a time. There is an event listener on each XHR request
that calls the callback like this:

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (oEvent) {
  if (oEvent.lengthComputable) {
    progressCallback(fileName, oEvent.loaded / oEvent.total);
  }
});
```

The progress callback looks like this:

```
function progressCallback(file, percentage){
    dispatch(updateFileInfo(file, percentage));
}
```

The dispatch call creates a new state with the new percentage information on one of the file nodes. There are connected (with react-redux) progress bar components associated with each file that re-render on each percentage change that has to do with the file they are associated with. There are container components that are connected to state as well but I have implemented shallow checks on those to ensure they don't redraw when that specific dispatch call is triggered.

The problem is that ~200 files or more, the entire application starts to slow to a crawl or even freezes the browser when the number of files gets large enough. My original thinking was that it was due to the constant rerendering or even just the logic in each progress bar's `mapStateToProps` function. However - removing the progress bars does not seem to make much of a difference at all. The issue seems to be in the many frequent dispatch calls and not due to the DOM redrawing. When I remove the dispatch calls from the callbacks the problem goes away.

My question is: is there an efficient way in Redux to issue thousands of dispatch calls (some of them asynchronously) in short succession that won't significantly slow down the application to the point that it is unusable?

Please let me know if there is any information that I have left out that would be helpful in solving this issue, thank you!

Comment: In order not to fall into general advises, just asking:

1. What profiling points to? I'd guess, some internals of "store.dispatch()" or it's wrappers.

2. Are http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Performance.html and it's links (such as https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/react-performance.md) helpful? Some of those are quite well-structured

Comment: I did look through most of those links. The closest thing I could find to the problem I am having is https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1751 and that person's problem seemed to be with the validation function. However running Timeline within Chrome Dev Tools points to `dispatch` as you just mentioned and nothing to do with the PropTypes validation functions.